# Query to fetch sent items in a conversation

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi

Currently i am using a below query which returns all mail items in a conversation which i feel pretty inefficient where i only require sent folder items. How to modify filter query to return items sent by current user.

Query :

```
let query = "ConversationId eq 'AAQkAGUzZmY0NThiLTUxMjAtNDBhNC05NGFkLTQ3NmRlYjlkMzRiNgAQAOO9BXAJn/VDvZTkMjcb52s='";
https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/Messages?$filter=encodeURIComponent(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scope your path to only the Sent Items folder:

`/me/mailFolders('SentItems')/messages$filter=encodeURIComponent(query)`

Comment: In outlook installed app, it is throwing error : {"error": {"code": "ErrorAccessDenied", "message": "The api you are trying to access does not support item scoped OAuth."}}. But this is working in web outlook. how to resolve this?

Comment: I don't follow. Are you attempting to execute this from within an Office.js add-in?

Comment: yes. this call is failing in installed outlook desktop webaddin.

Comment: It sounds like an authentication problem but  I've not seen that exact error message before. Are you using the SSO feature of Office.js or authenticating manually?

Comment: using Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true}, function(result){}) this to get access token after making rest api for sent mail itmes which is throwin error. It is failing in mac outlook only. working well in web browsers.

Comment: That call requires Mailbox v1.5 which is only available for OWA and some insider builds at the moment.

Comment: See https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets?product=outlook&version=v1.5 for more information.

Comment: what is the timeline to support v1.5 in mac and windows outlook? currently is supporting only v1.4.